# Using of parameter in class in Python

Tags: python, class, parameters

I met this question as I learned Python on Codecademy, code as below:

```
class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def greet(self, other):
        print "Hello, %s" % other.name

class CEO(Employee):
    def greet(self, other):
        print "Get back to work, %s!" % other.name

ceo = CEO("Emily")
emp = Employee("Steve")
emp.greet(ceo)
ceo.greet(emp)
```

I was wondering what does `other.name` mean here?

The `self.name = name` could be interpreted as a instance object's member variable `self.name` be set equal to `name`, so we can say that `self` is a instance and `name` is its property, right?

And, isn't the "Emily" assigned to the parameter `other` by `ceo = CEO("Emily")` and the "Steve" assigned to the `name` by `emp = Employee("Steve")`? How could it be used like that?

Comment: It is the name property of the "other" object, which is a parameter to that method.

Comment: other.name means "the `.name` property of the `other` object". other, which you passed emp to, is the employee object with the `.name` property "steve"

Comment: Note that e.g. `ceo.greet(emp)` resolves to `CEO.greet(ceo, emp)` - `ceo` is `self`, `emp` is `other`.

Answer (score 2):

## Class Attributes

`other.name` is the `name` attribute of any class instance that is passed as an argument to the `other` parameter of the `greet()` method.

### Extended Example

```
class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def greet(self, other):
        print "Hello, %s" % other.name

class CEO(Employee):
    def greet(self, other):
        print "Get back to work, %s!" % other.name

ceo = CEO("Emily")
emp = Employee("Steve")

print emp.name, 'greets', ceo.name
emp.greet(ceo)
print
print ceo.name, 'greets', emp.name
ceo.greet(emp)
```

---

```
Steve greets Emily
Hello, Emily

Emily greets Steve
Get back to work, Steve!
```

### Further inheritance explanation (edit)

`CEO` inherits everything defined by `Employee` (like the `name` attribute), but can alter things (like altering the `greet()` method).

Here is what is going on:

1. "Emily" is assign to the `name` attribute of the `CEO` class when an instance of that class is created as `ceo`.<sup>†</sup>

   ```
   ceo = CEO("Emily")
   ```
2. "Steve" is assigned to the `name` attribute of the `Employee` class when an instance of that class is created as `emp`.<sup>†</sup>

   ```
   emp = Employee("Steve")
   ```
3. In the an instance's `greet()` call, the *whole* other class instance is passed to it thru the `other` parameter of that method.

   ```
   emp.greet(ceo)
   ```

   This passes all of `ceo` into `emp.greet()`, so that `emp.greet()` can access something from `ceo`, in this case, the `name` of `ceo`.
4. The `greet()` call is repeated for the `ceo` instance

   ```
   ceo.greets(emp)
   ```

I hope this is clear, [read about and play](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) with some [other examples](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2014/06/18/improve-your-python-python-classes-and-object-oriented-programming/) of classes.

---

<sup>**†** : this is what the `__init__()` method is for. `__init__()` can take any argument, assign anything, or run any code. It is called whenever an instance of the class is created.</sup>

Comment: Thank you! But isn't the "Emily" assigned to the parameter `other` by `ceo = CEO("Emily")` and the "Steve" assigned to the `name` by `emp = Employee("Steve")`?

Comment: @markcodd This is the core of inheritance, see updated [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30003665/2087463).